# Byte[] to Long Using Bit Operations

Tags: java, byte, bit-manipulation, long-integer

I have a `byte[]` that holds the bytes to a long. I want to convert this to a long using bit operations. I have tried the following:

```
byte[] b = new byte[]{127, 127};
long result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    result <<= 8; // this is the same as l = l << 8;
    result |= (short)b[i] & 0xFF;
}
```

Which works for positive bytes. However the bytes can be both positive and negative so it doesn't work.

As an example:

```
byte[] b = new byte[]{-1, 2};
long result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    result <<= 8; // this is the same as l = l << 8;
    result |= (short)b[i] & 0xFF;
}
System.out.println(result);
System.out.println(new BigInteger(b).longValue());
```

Prints 65282 and -254. I believe the result from `BigInteger` is correct but I don't want to use it due to memory issues.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And can't you use a `ByteBuffer` instead?

Comment: A `long` is 8 bytes, not 2. If you left-shift a negative byte by 56 bits, the resulting `long` will be negative. You don't see it in your test because you are only left-shifting by 8 bits.

Comment: How do you really want to handle the bytes? In this situation I'd *expect* them to be handled as if they were 8 bit *unsigned* integers, in which case 65282 makes sense to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you need for your application.

```
byte[] b = new byte[] { -1, 2 }
```

Another way of looking at this is as the hexadecimal number 0xFF02. Does that represent a signed 64-bit value (65282)? Or a signed 16-bit value (-254)? Or an unsigned 16-bit value (65282 again)? Or an unsigned 64-bit value (still 65282)?

Your code treats it as a signed 64-bit value. `BigInteger` treats it as a signed 16-bit value. `BigInteger` has another constructor to treat the byte array as the magnitude, using a another parameter for the sign: `new BigInteger(+1, b)` would result in 65282.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I was using only two bytes for testing but if I use 8 bytes it works. Very dumb moment for me :P.

Comment: It could also be 767 for a little-endian representation.